# EntityFramework Core отображение enumeration в ms sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, xsd

Описываю структуру базы данных используя xsd схему (code first). Не совсем понимаю как правильно отобразить справочник в базу данных. Какую структуру использовать в данном случае? Создавать пустой класс и заполнять потом его или есть какой то более правильный метод.

```
<xs:element name="car" type="carType"/>

<xs:simpleType name="carType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: А это вопрос дискуссионный и возможно решён в вашем ТЗ. Если редактирования не подразумевается - можно и enum использовать, а можно и отдельную таблицу БД (класс, модель) CarType сделать с полями id, title. Я бы сделал отдельной таблицей.

Comment: @AK а можно подробнее про enum ?

Comment: Я поставлен в тупик. Что именно можно подробнее рассказать про enum? Обычный enum c#: public enum CarType {Audi, Golf,BMW } - ничего специфичного. EF его в базе никак не отразит, когда будете использовать в таблицах - ставите обычный `prop CarType Type { get; set; }`, в базе будет виден как число.

Comment: @AK спасибо, те в базе справочника не будет из этого перечисления? Или что вы имеете ввиду EF в базе его никак не отобразит?

Comment: При code first у вас есть классы (те что DbSet<> в DbContext), которые отображаются в таблицы базы данных, enum'ы в базе не будут создавать таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов два в общем-то (ну, так-то можно entity attribute value использовать): enum или класс.

В случае класса делаете обычный класс модели:

```
public class CarType
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

И прописываете в вашем DbContext:

```
public DbSet<CarType> CarTypes { get; set; }
```

В таблицах - штатное один-ко-многим:

```
public class Car
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int CarType { get; set; }
   public virtual CarType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Во втором случае делаете Enum:

```
public enum CarType
{
   Audi,
   Golf,
   BMW,
}
```

Прописывать в DbContext не нужно, отображения в базу данных Enum'ы не имеют.
Прописываете в нужных таблицах свойства:

```
public class Car
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public CarType Type { get; set; }
}
```

И в базе это будет просто число, а в коде получите enum при чтении из БД.

Каждый из вариантов имеет свои плюсы и минусы, я предпочитаю классический вариант с таблицей.

Comment: а еще можно ни как число записывать, а как текст (бывает, что такое тоже удобно). Для этого можно HasConversion использовать. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions